# Putting a variable into payload python requests

Tags: python, string, variables, python-requests

```
#real one
data = {'recipients' : '['+i+']'}
#one from requests
data = {'recipients' : '["908325719514423328"]'}
```

Hi, so i am trying to put a variable into the data but every time i try it is giving me `{'code': 50109, 'message': 'The request body contains invalid JSON.'}`, so i wonder if someone know how to put it in here i already tried `data = {'recipients' : f'["{i}"]'}` but didn't work i tried everything but nothing work, thanks you for helping! :)

The one i am currently trying is the #real one

Answer (score 1):

Use the `json=` parameter (which takes a dictionary) instead of `data=` (which takes a string)

```
r = requests.post(url, json={"key": "value"})
```